# SharePoint List with External Data Column not detecting records deleted from Source DB

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, bdc

I have a SharePoint 2010 list with an external data column connected to a MS SQL db. Everything is functioning as expected in terms of lookups and picking up any updates made to items in the DB but if an item is deleted in the DB it is not picked up on list refresh/sync.

Refresh successful.
0 item(s) were refreshed.
0 item(s) could not be refreshed because they no longer exist in TEST_SharePoint_BCS.

In the logs I see: 
Object not found while synchronizing business data item with ID __bg40003300, exception Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.ObjectNotFoundException: Null was returned to FindSpecific (Read Item operation).

Indicating the error is because no rows are returned. What I am confused about is why the message returned at the end of the refresh/sync indicates its looking for deleted items, yet errors out when one is found?